# Finding the linear mapping between homogeneous coordinates of affine camera

Tags: computer-vision, matrix

If I have an affine camera with a projection relationship governed by:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix}^T  = A
\begin{bmatrix}
X & Y & Z
\end{bmatrix}^T + b 
\end{equation} 
where A is a 2x3 matrix and b is a 2x1 vector. How can I form a matrix representing the linear mapping between the world point $(X,Y,Z)$ and image point $(x,y)$ if they are represented by homogeneous vectors?

Comment: Why isn't the equation in the question a linear mapping between the world point and the image point?